# Why does flex-direction work without display: flex being specified?

Tags: css, flexbox

Is it necessary to specify the display property when I have the flex-direction in a container. It seems to work just as fine but I'm afraid I'm breaking somethings:

```
.App {
    background-color: white;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding:15px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a working example? I see no `display` being mentioned in your code.

Comment: exactly, and it works as if the display property was there. no difference. and i'm wondering why and if i can just omit the display property when flex-direction is specified

Comment: `display` set to what? I don't understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a *block formatting context* (`display: block`), block elements consume the full width of their parent, by default. As a result, individual elements stack vertically.

*From the spec:*

> [**9.4.1 Block formatting
>   contexts**](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visuren.html#block-formatting)
>
> In a block formatting context, boxes are laid out one after the other,
>   vertically, beginning at the top of a containing block.

In a *flex formatting context* (`display: flex`), with `flex-direction: column`, individual items are also stacked vertically, resembling the layout in `display: block`.

So you're seeing similar behavior but, in fact, the `flex-direction` property is being ignored in the *block formatting context*.

Comment: Hi, can you explain more about this, I mean that why is flex-direction still works without specify display: flex?